# How can I run another function after if-else in a return Promise?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, request-promise

I have a logic trying to run a `rp` (request-promise) after if-else in a `then` process of a return Promise. From my assumption, I thought the process should go through step 1 to 10 (some parts might repeat and increase value). And after `solveProblem` finishes, finally, it goes to `doOther()`.

The following is the simplified version of my codes, even though it's a bit messy:

```
const request = require("request");
const rp = require("request-promise");
let url = "http://localhost:3000/";

let sendResult = c => {
  console.log("step 4", c);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (c < 5) {
      console.log("step 5 resolve(true)", c);
      resolve(true);
    } else {
      console.log("step 5 resolve(false)", c);
      resolve(false);
    }
  });
};

let repeat = (a, b) => {
  c = a + b;
  console.log("step 3", c);
  return sendResult(c).then(result => {
    console.log("step 6", result);
    if (!result) {
      console.log("step 7");
      rp(url).then(data => {
        console.log("step 8");
        let d = c + 1;
        if (d < 7) {
          console.log("step 9", d);
          return repeat(d, a);
        } else {
          console.log("step 10", d);
          return "done";
        }
      });
    } else {
      return repeat(c, a);
    }
  });
};

let solveProblem = (a, b) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(a + b);
  });
};

let doOther = () => {
  console.log("doOther");
};

let run = (a, b) => {
  console.log("step 1");
  solveProblem(a, b)
    .then(data => {
      console.log("step 2", data);
      return repeat(data, 1);
    })
    .then(() => {
      return doOther();
    });
};

run(1, 1);
```

However, the result is not as I expect. It postpones the `rp` and directly jump outside to another then to `doOther()`. After that, it continue `rp`. Like this:

```
step 1
step 2 2
step 3 3
step 4 3
step 5 resolve(true) 3
step 6 true
step 3 5
step 4 5
step 5 resolve(false) 5
step 6 false
step 7
doOther
step 8
step 9 6
step 3 9
step 4 9
step 5 resolve(false) 9
step 6 false
step 7
step 8
step 10 10
```

I am sure it's asynchronous problem, but I am not sure how I can modify it to make fit my requirement (step 1~10 then `doOther()`). Could anyone help me to figure it out? Thanks.

Comment: `rp(url).then` => `return rp(url).then` else it won't be chained

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Just what CertainPerformance said. Also, take a look at [Promise documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), it explains in detail what a promise can return and what happens then. And BTW, you can write solveProblem as `(a, b) => { Promise.resolve(a + b); }` (note the lack of `new`).

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks! It works like a charm.

Comment: @Frax Thanks!! I learned a new syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to return `rp(url)`
in order to chain it

```
...
return rp(url).then(data => {
    console.log("step 8");
    let d = c + 1;
    if (d < 7) {
      console.log("step 9", d);
      return repeat(d, a);
    } else {
      console.log("step 10", d);
      return "done";
    }
  });
...
```